# How to keep my user input on the same line after an output?

Tags: java, new-operator

I'm trying to write code that asks for the users age and then they enter it, but I want the number to appear next to the question after you enter it.

My code looks like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
num1 = userIn.nextInt();
```

It works fine, but the number always appears on the line below.

**Output:**

```
Enter a number:
12
```

**What I want:**

```
Enter a number: 12
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25):

Use `print()` instead of `println()`;

`System.out.println()` automatically adds a newline character. That what the `ln` means.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly. I looked everywhere and couldn't figure that out!

Comment: @user1332503: Be sure to accept the answer that helped you out the most, so we all know that your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

`System.out.print` instead of `println`.

println adds a newline after it prints your output, print will just print your message.

Answer (score 1):

Because you used `System.out.println` which adds a new-line (`\n`) after the output. Use `System.out.print` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.print()` instead of `println`. `Println` adds a new line after the arguments inside the **parameter** has been passed.